# Quasar's QDate locale prop doesn't works

Tags: vuejs2, localization, vue-component, quasar-framework

I try to localize QDate instance in my Quasar Vue.js application. But locale prop doesn't works.

```
<template lang="pug">
  q-date.no-borders(today-btn :value="temp" @input="update" :locale="currentLocale") 
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "LocalQDate",
  data() {
    return {
      temp: '',
      currentLocale: {
        days: 'Воскресенье_Понедельник_Вторник_Среда_Четверг_Пятница_Суббота_Воскресенье'.split('_'),
        daysShort: 'Вс_Пн_Вт_Ср_Чт_Пт_Сб'.split('_'),
        months: 'Январь_Февраль_Март_Апрель_Май_Июнь_Июль_Август_Сентябрь_Октябрь_Ноябрь_Декабрь'.split('_'),
        monthsShort: 'Янв_Фев_Мар_Апр_Май_Июн_Июл_Авг_Сен_Окт_Ноя_Дек'.split('_')
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update(newVal) { 
      this.temp = newVal;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Why QDate component doesn't see my locale settings? Manual says I am fully right. Maybe some error is here? [QDate API manual](https://v1.quasar-framework.org/vue-components/date#QDate-API)

[image: QDate is still in English]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved by updating quasar version 
[image: quasar upgrade -i]